# Passing Cython class object as argument to C function

Tags: python, c, cython, cpython

I am attempting to pass `Cython` instance class object as an argument to `C` function - so it can make a callback to its method.

This is what I have tried:

sample.c

```
#include "python.h"

void c_func(PyObject *obj){
    PyGILState_STATE gstate;
    gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

    /* Dictionary Object - can be of any dynamic type */

    PyObject *dict_obj = PyDict_New();
    PyObject *key = PyUnicode_FromString("average-run");
    PyObject *val = PyLong_FromLong(45445);
    PyDict_SetItem(dict_obj, key, val);

    /* Make a callback */

    PyObject_CallMethod(obj, "func_a", "(d)", dict_obj);

    PyGILState_Release(gstate);
}
```

pysample.pxd

```
cdef extern from "sample.h":
    void c_func(object obj)

cdef class Test(object):
    cdef func_a(self, object dict_obj)
```

pysample.pyx

```
cimport pysample
from pysample cimport Test

cdef class Test(object):
    cdef func_a(self, object dict_obj):
        print(dict_obj)

    def run_test(self):
        # Here I make a call to the C function
        pysample.c_func(self)
```

Unfortunately the callback from `C` doesn't work. Can you spot what I am doing wrong or suggest a fix to this ?

Comment: How is the c_func function supposed to get attached as a method of Test here? self.c_func seems like it should give an attribute error. Can you show the error when you compile, import, and attempt to call?

Comment: I missed the standalone cimport for pysample - I will edit the thread with it. Thanks

Comment: We still need to actually see you compile, load, and make a call to run_test so we can try to help debug.

Comment: Two things from the documentation that may help. 1) "d" in the format string is interpreted as a float, not a dictionary (https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue). 2) "Note that if you only pass `PyObject * args`, `PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs()` is a faster alternative." (https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html)

Comment: My strong suspicion is it will work if you change to callmethod line to: `PyObject_CallMethod(obj, "func_a", "(O)", dict_obj);` (pass the dict as a generic Python object).

Comment: One final thing: do you not need to handle the reference returned by `PyObject_CallMethod`?

Comment: Same is being used here https://monadical.com/posts/virtual-classes-in-cython.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. It was because the method in the class was defined as `cdef` instead of `cpdef`.

sample.c

```
#include "python.h"

void c_func(PyObject *obj){
    PyGILState_STATE gstate;
    gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

    /* Dictionary Object - can be of any dynamic type */

    PyObject *dict_obj = PyDict_New();
    PyObject *key = PyUnicode_FromString("average-run");
    PyObject *val = PyLong_FromLong(45445);
    PyDict_SetItem(dict_obj, key, val);

    /* Make a callback */

   PyObject *res = PyObject_CallMethod(obj, "func_a", "(O)", dict_obj);

   if( !res )
   {
       PyErr_Print();
   }else
   {
      Py_DECREF(res); 
   }
   /* 
    * Note: Do not remove reference counting
    * for callback argument - python will take
    * care of it when the callback python method
    * go out of scope. If you do - it will cause
    * inconsistent data behaviour at the callback 
    * method side.
    */

   PyGILState_Release(gstate);
}
```

pysample.pxd

```
cdef extern from "sample.h":
    void c_func(object obj)

cdef class Test(object):
    cpdef func_a(self, object dict_obj)
```

pysample.pyx

```
cimport pysample
from pysample cimport Test

cdef class Test(object):
    cpdef func_a(self, object dict_obj):
        print(dict_obj)

    def run_test(self):
        # Here I make a call to the C function
        pysample.c_func(self)
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! I'd missed the `cdef/cpdef/def` issue on my first look. Two more things you should fix (but weren't directly your core problem): 1) c_func doesn't return a `PyObject*` (but you say it does). 2) `PyObject_CallMethod` returns a `PyObject*` (probably to `None` for your specific test case) which you are supposed to decrement - you'll have a memory leak if you return anything non-trivial from `func_a`.

Comment: Also (at the end of `c_func`): `Py_DECREF(dict_obj); Py_DECREF(key); Py_DECREF(val);` and change the call to: `PyObject* res = PyObject_CallMethod( /* as before */); if (!res) { PyErr_Print(); } else { Py_DECREF(res); }`. There's a lot of reference counting involved in the C-api which is a bit of a nightmare really.

Comment: Another thing confusing me is that there are 2 `cdef class Test(object)`, is the one imported being overwritten in the `.pyx` file?

Comment: Yes. Think of the `.pxd` as the interface and `.pyx` as the implementation.